# How to do interval arithmetic on sympy 1.3?

Tags: python, sympy, intervals

How do I do interval arithmetic in Sympy 1.3?  (specifically, addition and multiplication)

For example, given:

```
q1 = Interval(0,255)
q2 = Interval(0,255)
```

The addition of those two intervals should be `Interval(0, 510)`.  (The plus operator is overloaded to mean "union", so q1+q2 yields Interval(0,255).)

If I try `Add(q1, q2)`, I get an exception:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/core/cache.py", line 93, in wrapper
    retval = cfunc(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/core/compatibility.py", line 850, in wrapper
    result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/core/operations.py", line 45, in __new__
    c_part, nc_part, order_symbols = cls.flatten(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/core/add.py", line 223, in flatten
    newseq.append(Mul(c, s))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/core/cache.py", line 93, in wrapper
    retval = cfunc(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/core/compatibility.py", line 850, in wrapper
    result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/core/operations.py", line 45, in __new__
    c_part, nc_part, order_symbols = cls.flatten(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/core/mul.py", line 186, in flatten
    r, b = b.as_coeff_Mul()
AttributeError: 'Interval' object has no attribute 'as_coeff_Mul'
```

(I get a similar exception for `Mul`).

Yet, the code to add two intervals seems to be right here:  https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/sympy-1.3/sympy/sets/handlers/add.py#L22

But the dispatcher mechanism doesn't seem to be catching the case of Interval + Interval.

How do I do addition and multiplication on intervals in sympy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sympy Intervals do not perform interval arithmetic. The function you found in the repository is one of the handlers for `sympy.sets.setexpr.SetExpr`, an expression type that takes values in a given set:

```
from sympy import Interval
from sympy.sets.setexpr import SetExpr

q1 = SetExpr(Interval(0, 255))
q2 = SetExpr(Interval(0, 255))

result = q1 + q2
```

`SetExpr` is currently hidden-ish and mostly undocumented.

Comment: Exactly. Beware that SymPy sets are trying to use operator overloading the way same way as Python sets, so most operations do not correspond to the interval arithmetic. Embedding the interval (or other SymPy sets) into SetExpr solves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `SetExpr(Interval(...))` you can also use `AccumBounds` which is older and was originally intended to give answers to "find the limit of `f`" where `f` is an oscillating function. As far as arithmetics is concerned it works about the same:

```
AccumBounds(3, 5) + AccumBounds(2, 8)  #  AccumBounds(5, 13)
AccumBounds(-2, 5) * AccumBounds(2, 8)  #  AccumBounds(-16, 40)
```

but there are some interval computations where the implementation of `AccumBounds` is more complete.

```
sin(AccumBounds(0, 3))  #  AccumBounds(0, 1)
sin(SetExpr(Interval(0, 3)))  #  SetExpr(ImageSet(Lambda(x, sin(x)), Interval(0, 3)))
```